# Jersey: how to use InjectableProvider with @Context annotation?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey

I followed [this post](http://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-injection-providers/) and created by first custom injectable provider, a `LocaleProvider` that scans the HTTP Request for the *Accept-Language* header. It works fine if I use it within a Jersey resource:

```
@Path("test")
@GET
public Response getStatus(@Context Locale locale) {
    log.finer("Locale: "+ locale);

    Response response = Response
            .noContent()
            .build();
    return response;
}
```

But when I want to use it in an `ExceptionMapper` I don't know how to inject the locale. I've tried to annotate it as a member variable:

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
  @Context
  private Locale locale;

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(MyException ex) {
    ...
  }
}
```

but this fails at deployment:

```
The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private java.util.Locale com.package.MyExceptionMapper.locale
```

Other things like `UriInfo` or `HttpServletRequest` *can* be injected like that. How do I get access to my own LocaleProvider?

FYI this is on Glassfish 3.1.1 using Jersey 1.8.

Comment: Hey Hank, were you ever able to get this LocaleProvider work with an ExceptionMapper?

Comment: Nope. I've implemented locale-detection inside the ExceptionMapper. I should probably close this question...

Answer (score 2):

There is a scope mismatch. ExceptionMapper is a singleton, while your injectable is per-request-scope. UriInfo works around it using ThreadLocals.

Comment: Thanks. In your opinion, what's the best way forward? Can I work around it using ThreadLocals, too? Or should I not worry about DRY and just implement the Locale-detection code inside the ExceptionMapper?